# Controlling WIFI\Cellular data update frequency on Android

Tags: java, android, client-server, battery

I am building a constantly living RESTful (well, just client server) mobile app which should be always connected to the internet on my Android device.

I'd like to configure the network threshold, so that when the app goes to idle state, instead of pinging the server from the mobile Android device (that runs on battery all the day long) every 50ms say, it would ping it every second [1000ms].

I think that after lots of digging I came across something, (after taking a look at some config file I once saw somewhere on IBM's doc pages) which is Java Mission Control - JMC, but I did not find the place where I can actually config anything relevant to these parameters (not that I succeeded to understand by far what JMC might be able to config in general...).

How would you save the battery's life in such a scenarios with a constant Cellular Data/WiFi usage?

Maybe praying for mercy can help...

Can I indeed approach it through some Java Mission Control (JMC) configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Java Mission Control doesn't configure java applications, it just collect data about their behavior. http://www.oracle.com/missioncontrol

Comment: So what does? How dan I go low level here?

Answer (score 0):

I found GCM - Google Cloud Messaging, which allows to send notifications to different platforms - iOS and Android ones alike. Those are allow you to take the initiation and establish a connection. By default messaging API won't kill your battarey.